# Providing updates to your Wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I've been doing a lot of research but can't find a straightforward way to provide updates to a Wordpress theme.

I have a custom theme I created for my blog and would like to provide updates to it from time to time.

How should I go about this?

Btw, I don't want the theme to be public.

Comment: Are you the only person who will ever use this? Or is this a theme you intend to be commercial? Can you be more specific about what you mean by updates?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'll be the only one using it

Comment: So by update what do you mean? Are you talking about making changes? Updating using the built in updater from a remote source? Pulling in changes from GitHub? It's a little ambiguous, I can think of 2 or 3 possible interpretations of your question right now, be specific and descriptive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an tutorial about wordpress automatic update [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181) 
and if you want to update it from github [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-your-plugins-in-github-with-automatic-updates--wp-34817)

I think you will find your answer there just follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one using it than just update the files on your server. If I'm  missing something please update the question with the additional info.

Comment: For educational purposes, I was more interested in pushing changes and having each update show up in the updates section of wordpress.

Comment: if you are in a educational way, the first step to learn in coding is to separte the work with datas and the presentation of these datas. then you will see that the work with data wich is done with plugins, is more usefull to be updated. and to control plugin update, look the filter `pre_set_site_transient_update_plugins`